# Doxygen substitute element at the beginning of the line that is repeated in file

Tags: sed, doxygen

I am trying to generate documentation using doxygen for a not-supported format similar to a makefile. I have lines that look as this:

```
001: $(SOME_DYNAMIC_TARGET): some_function
002:
003:///Documentation for Doxygen
004:///
005:///
006:fixed_target: $(REDIRECTION_TO_OTHER_TARGET)
```

I only care about the fixed_target and not the dynamic one, so I try to use sed one-liners as INPUT_FILTER in order to change my code to a C-like structure. I would expect to see this after dumping the preprocessor with `doxygen -d Preprocessor` :

```
001:
002:
003:///Documentation for Doxygen
004:///
005:///
006:fixed_target= $(REDIRECTION_TO_OTHER_TARGET);
```

My INPUT_FILTER looks like this

```
INPUT_FILTER = "sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/\1=\2;/; s/^\$/#/'"
```

This should switch the `:` for an `=`, add a semicolon at the end of my target line and replace the `$` at the beginning of the first line with a `#` which will make the preprocessor of doxygen ignore that line. However, the `s/^\$/#/` part does not work properly, since it proceeds to replace the first `$` sign that it finds in each line, even if it is not at the beginning, so I end up with this instead:

```
001:
002:
003:///Documentation for Doxygen
004:///
005:///
006:fixed_target= #(REDIRECTION_TO_OTHER_TARGET);
```

I still get the documentation out, but that unwanted `#` in line 006 is a side-effect that I want to avoid when my code becomes more complex. Have I done something wrong with my filter?

Comment: It would appear that Doxygen and/or the shell is performing some amount of parsing on the string you pass in.  I'm not familiar with Doxygen, but I'm guessing that it does ... something with the caret.

Comment: I would test what happens if I removed the space in the middle of "= $" by adding a space behind the colon in the input filter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried removing the space in the middle, but still got "=#" as a result, so my guess is triplee is right and Doxygen might be doing something weird with the caret

Answer (score 0):

Your sed should be (assuming header line `001:` is not in the file but just for information)

```
sed 's/:/=/;s/^\$/#/;s/$/;/'
```

so passed from an external appli to a subshell, you certainly need to escape some char

```
INPUT_FILTER = "sed 's/:/=/;s/^\\\$/#/;s/\$/;/'"
```

Comment: The filter as suggested ended up  changing all `$` for `;`.
Unfortunately, lines like `001:` are in the file and I cannot exclude all of them from Doxygen parsing with `\cond`, since it creates syntax problems in some cases. I'll see if it is a problem from Doxygen side or try to find a work around